# Adding Credentials to diffrent account from local system account

Tags: c#, powershell, credentials, octopus-deploy

Were using octopus for deployment, the tentacle is running as "local system account" I would like the tentacle to add credentials for a diffrent account. However I have no luck i doing so.

So far i tried creating a c# program which starts a new process as the other user, and the calls the cmdkey.exe

```
    private static void CallCmdKey(string runAsDomain, string runsAsUser, string runAsPass, string target, string user, string pass)
    {

        System.Diagnostics.Process proc = new System.Diagnostics.Process();

        proc.StartInfo.Arguments = $"/generic:{target} /user:{user} /pass:{pass}";
        proc.StartInfo.FileName = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("WINDIR") + "\\system32\\cmdkey.exe";
        Console.Out.WriteLine(proc.StartInfo.Arguments);
        proc.StartInfo.Domain = runAsDomain;
        proc.StartInfo.UserName = runsAsUser;
        proc.StartInfo.LoadUserProfile = true;


        SecureString sec = new SecureString();
        runAsPass.ToCharArray().ToList().ForEach(sec.AppendChar);
        proc.StartInfo.Password = sec;
        proc.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = ".";

        proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;

        proc.Start();
        proc.WaitForExit();
        Console.Out.WriteLine("done");
    }
```

But it fails with access denied.

Then i tried power shell and psexec like this:

```
$psexec = "C:\temp\psexec.exe"
Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock{&$psexec -accepteula -u $WEB02AP2User -p $GISWEB02AP2Pass cmd /c cmdkey /generic:ffff /user:mufasa /pass:yoyo}
```

but it fails with

Access is denied. 
PsExec could not start cmd: 
The remote script failed with exit code 5

For security reasons Im not allowed to change account for the tentacle service

How can i sovle this issue

Comment: Would not [Running Tentacle Under a Specific User Account](https://octopus.com/docs/infrastructure/deployment-targets/windows-targets/running-tentacle-under-a-specific-user-account) solve your problem?

Comment: @fredrik it would, but im not allowed to change the account

Comment: Try setting `proc.CreateNoWindow = true`. System services are not allowed to interact with the desktop.

Comment: As a general note: (a) you have your user and password in the PS example (hopefully only examples). (b) if you execute in such a way, the user/password will be visible on the system in question using tools like Task Manager, that can display the command line of running process. That might not be a concern for you or your situation, but you should be aware of it anyway. You might be better of using the "Credential Manager API" directly (search "windows credential manager api c#").

Comment: @fredrik proc.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true; Sadly didnt do the job.

Comment: @Christian.K Its only example data. I have tried to look into the Credential Manager API, however it doesnt solve the problem with adding credentials for diffrent users

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Was unable to find a solutions to this issue. Only workaround was to let the octopusservice run as a specific user account